# Create new vm with aws api

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk

Is there a way to create or destroy virtual machines with aws api? I could not find a very comprehensive resource on it. I am trying to use this for being a dynamic web host.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible using the EC2 API ('RunInstances' docs [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/API_RunInstances.html)). Alternatively if you're dealing with an expanding and contracting pool of instances you might want to look into Auto Scaling Groups (docs [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/latest/userguide/AutoScalingGroup.html)).